# Using .htaccess to change url from one image to another url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I just migrated a website from one URL to another. Unfortunatly the last web dev used absolute urls everywhere. There is one image that is requesting the old url and because it's part of a image slider it takes up to a minute before the slider loads on the homepage (needs to timeout, I've looked... I can't find where this image is being called from in the extensive database and thousands of files).

My question is, can I use htaccess to rewrite any requests to the old url to the new url so I don't have to manually track down this image call?

I tried Redirect http://123.com/* http://456.com/* 
where 123.com is my old url and 456.com is my new url, doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: If you send a request to your old domain, you would have to have a .htaccess file redirecting them on that old domain. Why not do a mass find/replace?

Comment: If he has standard source code, this would obviously be pretty simple. If he's using something like Drupal this request could be a huge pain to find.

Comment: You have to find and change the url on your site because once you shut down the site at the old host, that image will become broken. Additionally, the .htaccess file to redirect that would have to reside on the OLD server not the new one as Jonathon mentioned above.

Comment: I don't have access to the old url or server. A find and replace isn't a solution, it would take me forever. I'm not a regex guru, so if my old url was http://123.com and my old image was being called as http://123.com/images/image.jpg but the new url and image is located at http://456.com/images/image.jpg, how would I rewrite that?

Comment: You can't, since you no longer have access to your old server or domain. Your only real option if you want to implement a redirect is to get access to the old domain. When a URL is requested, your browser will look at the domain, i.e. 123.com, and find the location of the server using the domain name service (DNS). That's just how web browsers work, they follow the standard protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with mod_rewrite of Apache2 (if you are using it, there are similar way for others web server).

Here is the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html